# School time management system

Tags: time, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to learn UML and I would like to design a time management system in which

- a school has classes with a fixed time schedule during the school year.

Knowing that the

- courses are divided into sessions,
- which are themselves divided into time slots,

I arrived at the following class diagram with these relationships. I am not yet interested in the types of relationships or attributes but more in the cardinalities and the classes themselves. I would like to know if my system is coherent so far, i.e. the classes listed and the relationships between them make sense.

[image]

Comment: Don't expand as you go along. Ask a single specific question each.

Comment: Also review questions are no good fit here. Often they get an answer, but there are other StackExchange sites for that kind of question.

Comment: I don't know them

Comment: Google helps: "stackexchange review" just the first hit.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here:

- your `Class` has only one `Schedule` with one `School_year` so the next year you need a new system, I guess.
- `Sessions` are divided in "time slots" but there's no such class. Probably it's `time_period` but there's also only one for a `Session`.

Your naming should use singular in all cases. Also classes should start with a capital letter as per convention. `Dept` could be deputy as well as department. Don't shorten names where the meaning gets unclear.

Comment: Thanks you @qwerty_so. I made some adjustments to what you advised me and I came up with the following result. But I have some problems with what you said above. I would like to be able to create timetables according to the class and for each class to have its own personal timetable. Why use a multiple relationship in this case? Some methods of analysis would use a one-to-one relationship to indicate that a class has a schedule. The same question applies to time use and school year.  https://imgur.com/a/Dasn5HA this is the link of the edited picture of my class diagram.

Comment: @MarK: Drop the getters/setters, they are just noise, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139621/shortcut-for-denoting-or-implying-getters-and-setters-in-uml-class-diagrams/28141950#28141950. Better don't use the white diamond (for aggregation), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476608/the-difference-between-aggregation-and-association-in-implementation/58502745#58502745. What are the strange dots at the source and target of the dependency arrow supposed to mean? And what is the dependency supposed to express?

Comment: @GerdWagner I think the dots are asterisks (so noise too). As I mentioned: this is not a place for ping-pong answers.

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: Follow the above advices/comments or don't. Decide yourself.